# How to use alternate config file when compiling the Kernel?

Tags: kernel

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as host, and I plan to compile a new kernel. I downloaded the Linux-Libre kernel. When compiling the kernel, I would like to "Load alternate configuration".

I have an alternate kernel config, which is not the default Ubuntu config. How to use the alternate configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an alternate kernel config, which is not the default Ubuntu config. How to use the alternate configuration ?

It is as simple as copying the alternate `.config` to the top-level linux kernel source directory. You can check if it's the top-level by verifying with `ls` that the `Kbuild` or `Kconfig` files exist in the directory.

Then compile your kernel as usual (`make-kpkg`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you izx for the reply. I copied it to the extracted directory and was able to perform my work.

Comment: Happy to help @RoshanGeorge; please accept/upvote the answer in that case. Thanks!